# Droppable doesn't fire after changing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to simulate an animate effect via jQuery that consists drag and drop as events to be fired. The code I use seems to be fine until the point when I have to swap divs by setting their **display** to *none/block*. Whenever I swap to the first div it perfectly executes the animation but when it gets on the 2nd div (after swapped) it doesn't fire the droppable event. I chose to have id selectors for the respective divs to instance the container of the droppable event hence to animate. I'm stuck and are out of any solution after searching numerous results so far. Thank you in advance. Here is my JS fiddle I prepared to easily understand my problem.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
    #wrapper    {
                        border: 1px solid gray;
                        height:300px;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;                   
                        position:relative;
                        text-align:center;                  
                        width:600px;                                
                }
    p {
                        display:inline;
                        font-family:Calibri; 
                        font-size:20px;
                        color: #0b1207;
                        text-shadow: #63c9b8 0px 10px 10px;
    }

    #div1, #div2 {
                        border: 1px dotted green;
                        bottom:0;
                        margin-left:100px;
                        position: absolute;
                        }

    #div1 {
                        background-color: orange;                    
                        height:200px;                    
                        width:300px;
    }

    #div2 {
                        background-color: green;
                        display:none;
                        height:100px;
                        width:300px;                    
    }

    #btnchange {
                        background-color:black;
                        border-radius:10px;
                        color: #fff;
                        height:35px;
                        margin-top:10px;
                        margin-left:100px;
                        position:absolute;
                        width:80px;
    }

    .example {
                        border: 1px solid red;  
                        background-color: blue;
                        height:75px;
                        margin: 5px auto 0 ;
                        width:75px;                 
                    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id='wrapper'>
    <p></p>
    <div id='div1'></div>
    <div id='div2'></div>
</div>

<button id ='btnchange' type='button'>Change</button>

<div class='example'></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://biostall.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/jquery-swapsies.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


                var id = 1;
                var parent = document.getElementById('wrapper');
                var makina = parent.children[id].id;

                $(function(){

                    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
                              connectToSortable: "#sortable",
                              helper: "clone",
                              revert: "invalid"
                    });

                    $('.example').draggable({
                              containtment: "#" + makina, 
                              cursor: "pointer", 
                              revert: true
                    });

                    $('#btnchange').click(function(){
                        if (id == 1)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(makina).style.display = 'none'; 
                            id = 2;
                            makina = parent.children[id].id;
                            document.getElementById(makina).style.display = 'block';  
                            document.getElementById('wrapper').children[0].innerText = makina;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            document.getElementById(makina).style.display = 'none'; 
                            id = 1;
                            makina = parent.children[id].id;
                            document.getElementById(makina).style.display = 'block';     
                            document.getElementById('wrapper').children[0].innerText = makina;
                        } 
                        console.log(makina);       
                    });

                    $("#" + makina).droppable({
                            drop: function(){
                                doAnimate(makina);}
                    }); 

                });

                 function doAnimate(container)
                {
                    $('#'+ container).animate({height: '+=10px'}, 500, function(){
                                    var message = container.clientHeight;
                                    $(this).html(message);
                    });
                }

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xoxxbr4t/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Michal indeed that was the answer but I think a good programmer would reduce the redundant snippet of code as far as I can tell those are duplicate lines from the $(document).ready() function. However it's a solution. And right after I read your post I decided to post the answer myself as it follows:

```
//Previous
$("#" + makina).droppable({
    drop: function () {
        doAnimate(makina);
    }
});

//Current
$("#wrapper").droppable({
    drop: function () {
        doAnimate(makina);
    }
});
```

Since I'm using nested divs I then realised that I could make the parent div droppable and just animate the child which is active(shown).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you were only calling droppable once, on only one of the items. Once the .droppable() function is also put inside the change button click, it should work.

put this inside change function:

```
$("#" + makina).droppable({
    drop: function () {
        doAnimate(makina);
    }
});
```

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xoxxbr4t/7/

Answer (score 1):

You aren't binding droppable to your second element. You call this function once:

```
$("#" + makina).droppable({
    drop: function () {
        doAnimate(makina);
    }
});
```

Since your "makina" at this point is div1, that's the only thing that gets bound. I made that it's own function:

```
function setDroppable(makina) {
 $("#" + makina).droppable({
    drop: function () {
        doAnimate(makina);
    }
});  
}
```

And then called it for both divs in your setup:

```
setDroppable('div1');
setDroppable('div2');
```

And now it works fine. Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xoxxbr4t/8/)

Comment: Thank's that is indeed another approach to the solution. But I think that wouldn't become dynamic in terms if we have to change/swap more than two divs in the same parent div.